# Passing values to User Control from Form

Tags: c#

I've created User Control in my WFA (Windows Form Application) and I want to pass value from my `MainForm.cs` to `UserControl.cs` but I have no idea on how to do that. Here are my values I want to pass to the `UserControl.cs`

```cs
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
        private void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
             if (ProcOpen)
             {
                 //THESE 
                 int vlInt = m.ReadByte("base+007C1DAC,0x14,0x4");

                 int roomID = m.ReadByte("base+003CA150,0x0");

                 double diffValue = m.ReadDouble("base+007B4A3C,0x0,0x2c,0x10,0x7ec,0x300");
             }
       }
}
```

To

```cs
public partial class FirstCustomControl : UserControl
    {
        public FirstCustomControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FirstCustomControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //GET THE VALUES HERE
        }

    }
```

Comment: Pass it to where in the user control? All you have there is a constructor, and your control will already be, well... *constructed*.

Comment: My bad edited the question.

Comment: You're trying to pass a value from a `ProgressChanged` event to the UC's `Load` event? I don't see how that would work. Unless you're doing dynamic UI work, the control will likely be created and loaded onto the form already. This event would be fired and finished. Normally you'd have a property or method of the UC you could pass your value to.

Comment: That's why i asked the question. If there is anyway to get the values to the UserControl.

Comment: Are you creating the UserControl dynamically from the ProgessChanged() event?...or is it already on the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a property for your UC then set the property from the parent;

```
public partial class FirstCustomControl : UserControl
{

    public static dynamic vlInt;
    public static dynamic roomID; 
    public static dynamic diff; 



    public FirstCustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void NotifyValueChanged(){
           label1.text = vlInt.ToString();
           label2.text = roomID.ToString();
           label3.text = diff.ToString();

    }
    private void FirstCustomControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Then in your MainForm

```
    public partial class MainForm : Form
{
        private void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
             if (ProcOpen)
             {
                 //THESE 
                 FirstCustomControl.vlCount = m.ReadByte("base+007C1DAC,0x14,0x4");

                 FirstCustomControl.roomID = m.ReadByte("base+003CA150,0x0");

                 FirstCustomControl.diff = m.ReadDouble("base+007B4A3C,0x0,0x2c,0x10,0x7ec,0x300");
                 firstCustomControl1.NotifyValueChanged();
             }
       }
}
```

Comment: Edited the code to what I did so I can mark it as an answer. This helped me a lot, thanks :). Also I'm not totally sure if my solution for it is the best but it works :D

Comment: @txshiro if you want to send those values from BackgroundWorker it's better to check if your controls requried to Invoke first !  if (label1.txt.InvokeRequired) ...

Comment: Already did that and thanks! Also i now ruined your 420 reputation. I'm sorry mate.